# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ArgumentParser' and 'int' - argparse datetime hours and minutes

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to use `argparse` to parse a command line argument, as hours and minutes `%H:%M`, like this:

```
import croniter
import datetime
import re
import sys
import time
import argparse
from sys import argv

now = argparse.ArgumentParser() #datetime.datetime.now()
now.add_argument('date', type=lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M'))

def main():
    f = sys.stdin
    f1 = f.readlines() 
    for x in f1:
        if not re.match('^[0-9*]', x):
            continue
        a = re.split(r'\s+', x)
        cron = croniter.croniter(' '.join(a[:5]), now)
        print("%s %s" % (cron.get_next(datetime.datetime), ' '.join(a[5:])))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I use this script like this `python myfile.py 14:45 < /etc/crontab`

It should parse the crontab file, read it's contents, and print at what time every task will run given the hours and minutes argument.

Everything works fine until I try to add the argument parser to the script.

As You can see the previous version was using `now=datetime.datetime.now()` and it was working perfectly, I just need to change that to  a given argument on console.

Right now it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cron.py", line 24, in <module>
main()
File "cron.py", line 21, in main
print("%s %s" % (cron.get_next(datetime.datetime), ' '.join(a[5:])))
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rest_tails2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/croniter/croniter.py", line 103, in get_next
return self._get_next(ret_type or self._ret_type, is_prev=False)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rest_tails2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/croniter/croniter.py", line 193, in _get_next
nth_weekday_of_month, is_prev)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rest_tails2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/croniter/croniter.py", line 235, in _calc
dst = now = self._timestamp_to_datetime(now + sign * offset)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ArgumentParser' and 'int'
```

This is the offending line: `print("%s %s" % (cron.get_next(datetime.datetime), ' '.join(a[5:])))`

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Your `now` is a parser, and object of type `ArgumentParser`.  It isn't the result of parsing the command line.  `args = now.parse_args()` will create a `argparse.Namepace` object.  `args.date` should be a `datetime` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call the parser, and `now` is the parser, not a date.

Since you only have the one argument, you can parse and get that argument by adding this line after your `add_argument` call:

```
now = now.parse_args().date
```

Now your variable `now` has two meanings (first it's the parser, then it's the value of the `date` arg), which can be a little confusing sometimes, but it'll work. A clearer way to write that section would be:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('date', type=lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M'))
args = parser.parse_args()
now = args.date
```

Of course `now` is now a misnomer since it's not necessarily today, so you could rename that variable as well.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to take the argument and parse it:

```
input1 = sys.argv[1]
now = datetime.datetime.strptime(input1, '%H:%M')
```

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" this in my code by:

```
parser.parse_args()
blocks = args.blocksize
overlap = blocks // 2 # this used to fail with 
    'blocks' being none
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30698599)